# how to extract every data using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of nested dictionaries that has three keys. I need to convert them in dataframe. I am using `for` loop and its reading every element in the column, but only showing the last keys of the list. What and where am I missing another loop?

I have two columns, one has ids and other has notes. ids are unique and to every id there is notes that is list of nested dictionary. It has timestamp, createdby and status in text. For one id there are many status created at different timestamps by different people. I have tried for loop and Dataframe() funtion.

```
for i in df1.candidateNotes:
    data = pd.DataFrame(i)
    print(data)
```

I am expecting separate columns showing status updates with time and who created it.

Comment: What is `i` in this case?

Comment: Could you please show us what your table look like and what is the desired output?

Comment: id     status1                  status2        status3        status4     status5   ......                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123   initial submission     cv review    interview1    interv2    interview3
         createdAt: datetime  datetime     datetime     datetime    datetime
          createdby : abc        crby: def     crby:fgh      crby:tyu      crby: iop

Comment: i did it on my own,,, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) method.

```py
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    print(row.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you want to print every value on column candidateNotes with the format like a dataframe?

```
for _,row in df1.iterrows():
    data = pd.DataFrame(row.candidateNotes)
    print(data)
```

Does this work?

Comment: only last row of data is coming in the dataframe. i needed all rows. when i am using data.head(). i get only last row. i should get first five rows

Comment: @AamerAshfaque please edit your question with some sample of your "df1" dataframe, because I can't determine what your dataset looks like according to your description.